# Angular enable tooltip even if page is disabled

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

I am using a button inside a `<td>` in my Angular 8 application and inside the  I have a button with a tool-tip `( title="{{data.footNote}}" )`. I am using a directive which disables the entire page. Although the page is disabled I need to have the tool tip enabled. Is this possible?
I tried `disabled= false` and then apply `button:disabled`

```
`{cursor: pointer !important; pointer-events: all;}
```

and that works but I cannot have `disabled=false` because that leaves the button disabled all the time.

Comment: You can make button disabled conditional, when you apply disabled directive make button disabled else enable.

Comment: Thanks Kamran, yes but how do I identify if the directive is applied to the page

Comment: Cant tell without reviewing the code.